# grails searchable for grails 2.1.0?

Tags: grails, version, grails-searchable

Can anyone please tell me what is the searchable plugin version works with grails-2.1.0? When I add the searchable plugin with version 0.6.4 (via maven dependency) I'm getting this error when I'm building the project

Plugin: searchable - Dependencies: - dataSource (Required: 1.0 > *, Found: 2.1.0) - domainClass (Required: 1.0 > *, Found: 2.1.0) - i18n (Required: 1.0 > *, Found: 2.1.0) - core (Required: 1.0 > *, Found: 2.1.0)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried it with Grails 2.2+..
On the plugin site, under description they have mentioned that ***"Only versions 0.6.4+ work with Grails 2.2+ "***
So may be there is some compatibility problem of Searchable-0.6.4 with older Grails version